# How to create Samsung One UI's like viewing area using recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to create Samsung One UI's like viewing area which is implemented in e.g settings. It makes every item from the list reachable with one hand. It shows up when user scrolls down (but only if user is already on the top of the list).

I could add item of another type to the recycler view at the top but I don't know how to make this item show up only when user scrolls down and also not show up when first inflating this recycler view

gif presenting what I am talking about

[image]

Comment: To get more/better help, I recommend posting an animation of the Samsung One UI, or something else to help those who are not familiar with it, and your current code.

Comment: I would recommend you to read from here https://medium.com/@tonia.tkachuk/appbarlayout-scroll-behavior-with-layout-scrollflags-2eec41b4366b

Comment: @DemoDemo  this gives me a general idea how to do this,but  still don't know how to achieve this scroll down twice to get to the viewing area. (you can see overscroll animation twice)